# Calculated columns giving me values to thirteen decimal places

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column

I have some calculated columns in a SharePoint list and a using an InfoPath form to make it look a bit nicer.

[image]

The total for each line is based on the uint price multiplied by the quantity. The sub total is the addition of the totals on each line. The grand total is the sub total, plus handling, plus VAT.

Despite each field being set to 2 decimal places, all my totals are to 15 digits, whether it is a 1-digit number with 14 decimal places, or 2-digit with 13 decimal places, etc.

Am I doing something wrong to be getting this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem - the result of the calculated column was being formatted in Inforpath as text and not as a decimal. For future reference, this can be changed like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the properties of the Total Field what you have their, I tested as per your scenario and every thing works as expected.

Go to List setting and Under the Column click on the Total Column.

1. Make sure Number is selected(if you want numbers only)
2. and from Number of Decimals Places...make sure 2 selected.

Comment: the list columns were already set up this way